# Evaluating trig functions for a point that passes through...

Tags: trigonometry

I have the question "Evaluate the trig functions for angle a in standard position whose terminal side passes through (3, 4): Sec a, csc a, and cot a.

For cot a the answer given is 3/4, which makes sense because, as I double checked in the back of the book even, cot a = x/y. But for sec it says the answer is 5/3. Though in the back sec a is defined as 1/x.

So, how are they getting to that answer?

Comment: $sec $ is $1/x$ if the point $(x,y)$ is on the unit circle. but the point $(3, 4)$ is not on the unit circle. in fact it is on the circle of radius $5.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secant should actually be $\frac{r}{x}$ where $r$ is the radius.  It is $\frac{1}{x}$ if you are on the unit circle.

Comment: Thanks, this added to abel's comment finally got me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Drop a line from the point $(3,4)$ perpendicular to the x-axis. Your triangle is created with that line you just drew, a line to the point $(3,4)$ from the origin, and the x-axis from 0 to $(4,0)$. Now use the elementary definitions of the trig functions, eg, $\sin \theta=\frac{OPP}{HYP}$,etc. You can use the Pythagorean theorem to find the diagonal length and use basic trigonometry to find the values of the trig functions.